# why does the app skips the LoginActivity to HomeActivity?

Tags: android-studio

I have added these lines on LoginActivity to make sure that users stay logged in:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
```

it works, it keeps the user logged in and always open the app in HomeActivity unless the user signs out..

but when I go from signupActivity to loginActivity. it goes directly to HomeActivity. it skips the Login and goes to HomeActivity. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the user object of? Add more snippets to support your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line in signupActivity before calling intent of LoginActivity

```java
auth.signOut() // FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```